# Recursion Time Complexity Involving String Concatenation

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

Recently, I was completing leetcode problem [#1022](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-root-to-leaf-binary-numbers/), sum of root to leaf binary numbers. Below is my solution code:

```
class Solution:
    def sumRootToLeaf(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        self.val = 0

        def dfs(root, path):
            if not root.right and not root.left:
                self.val += int(path + str(root.val), 2)
                return
            
            if root.right:
                recurse(root.right, path + str(root.val))
            
            if root.left:
                recurse(root.left, path + str(root.val))
        
        dfs(root, "")

        return self.val
```

While this passed, I began thinking about its time complexity. At this point, I became somewhat stumped. My thinking is as follows:

For time complexity, we are going to call our `dfs()` function on every single node; therefore, there will be N total calls. Within the function itself, we will be completing a string concatenation, which is an `O(k)` operation, where `k` represents the total characters in our combined strings. In this case, at worst, we will be concatenating a single character to a path variable of size `H`, where `H` is the height of the tree. Therefore, is time complexity `O(NH)`, where `N` is the number of nodes in the tree and `H` is the height of the tree?